# Can I see who follows a certain tag?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, users

I wonder whether it is possible to see which users are following a specific tag.
If I hover my mouse on a tag I can see *how many* users are following this tag but I'm not able to see *who* follows this tag. Although I can assume that some of the people in the *Top Answerers* list are following this tag, this is obviously not enough.

[image]

Is there any way to do so? If not, what do you think of adding it?

Comment: No way to do that, and not sure it will be good idea. Many people aren't happy with the information not being private to begin with, i.e. anyone can see what tags a user is subscribed to in their [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=subscriptions). So having such a list will make it much "worse".